# Creating a new scratchpad on an existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://github.com/websanova/wScratchPad/blob/master/src/wScratchPad.js

I have a button that creates an scratch pad on an element by ID. (`$("#test").wScratchPad({optionshere}`);

And it works just fine, but then I want to click the button and generate a new one. (the numbers are randomly generated on the image)

But, I've tried:

```
    1. Using $("#test").wScratchPad("destroy");
    2. Using $("#test").wScratchPad("clear");
    3. Using $("#test").wScratchPad("reset");
```

And after one of ^, I've tried recreating the wScratchPad with the same code. (It's all in a click event)

But:

```
Destroy -> Just doesn't generate a new image
Clear -> Is just used for clearing the scratch stuff
Reset -> Just reset the overlay image that you scratch off
```

and I can't make it re-place the image. I've also tried doing something like:

```
    $("#test").children().remove();

->

    *createscratchpadhereon#test*
```

Sorry but I couldn't get it to understand that I don't have any more code to indent. I indented every piece of code but it still refused to let me post, so yeah.

Comment: Thanks, was going crazy.

Comment: I tried to make it remove the div, and re-create it with a different ID, but then it refuses to create the Scratcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this. Apparently I couldn't create a new scratchpad on an existing one, (perhaps my fault, idk) so I decided to simply remove the old div, and create a new one.

This wouldn't work either. Now I finally figured out I could do that (the removing & recreating of the div) if I added the CSS that was required, using *ELEMENT*.css().css() etc. (the element required a certain width/height)

Not sure why it wouldn't work to just replace it with my current scratchpad (since it would keep the CSS) but oh well! Works.